# Different docker compose override for custom Visual Studio configuration

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

We have a fairly complex system using docker-compose with a lot of different microservices. I want to be able to run an individual microservice via visual studio with one docker-compose configuration (Debug).  Alternatively, I have another configuration (lets call it Debug2) where I want a slightly different docker-compose configuration.

Right now my "docker-compose.yml" file has the basics, and my "docker-compose.override.yml" has some development specific things. I made a "docker-compose.debug.yml".  When I run the project in Debug mode, it launches all 3 of those files.

All is well so far, right?

Well, then I tried making a "docker-compose.debug2.yml".  I added a new configuration to the project and solution called "Debug2". When I try running from Visual Studio in that mode, it only launches with the first 2 files, and doesn't attempt to use the "debug2" file at all.

Is the system hardcoded to only allow Debug and Release override files? Did I do something wrong or is there an oversight? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you are running the services via compose, are you passing the optional override file as well?

For example,

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.debug.yml -f docker-compose.debug2.yml`

By default, compose only looks for a `docker-compose.overrides.yml` to my knowledge. Therefore, you would have to pass it as an optional argument when you spin up your environment.

"By default, Compose reads two files, a docker-compose.yml and an optional docker-compose.override.yml file. By convention, the docker-compose.yml contains your base configuration. The override file, as its name implies, can contain configuration overrides for existing services or entirely new services."

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this issue you can find documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2019

The two specific file names for "debug" and "release" are:

```
docker-compose.vs.debug.yml
docker-compose.vs.release.yml
```